# Как создать такой переключатель?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

[image: Всем привет! Подскажите пожалуйста как создать такой элемент?]

Всем привет! подскажите пожалуйста как создать вот такой вот элемент? Я думаю, что можно как-то кастомизировать SegmentedConroll, но как не понимаю.. может быть можно как-то кнопки кастомизировать?

Answer (score 1):

1. Создать новый:

Создается класс, наследуется от UIView. На него добавляются 3 кнопки UIButton. Обрабатываются нажатия.

2. Кастомизировать UISegmentedControl (сложнее):

Создать класс, наследовать от UISegmentedControl. В необходимом методе после инициализации ковырять subviews и изменять их программно до нужного функционала.

О том как создавать собственные контролы есть [хороший туториал на англ](https://www.raywenderlich.com/36288/how-to-make-a-custom-control).

Comment: Спасибо, а как сделать кнопки подчёркнутыми?

Comment: Если есть кнопка `UIButton *button` и текст `NSString *text`, тогда так:
`[button setAttributedTitle:[NSAttributedString initWithString:text attributes:@{NSUnderlineStyle: @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)}] forState:UIControlStateNormal]`

Comment: но лучше выставить для состояния UIControlStateSelected, и просто выбирать нужную кнопку как выделенную